# Go SFTP server exits after one client connection

Tags: go, ssh, sftp

I've been playing with this example [https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/master/examples/go-sftp-server/main.go](https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/ec1c8caca60e03e3816cadfaad20a0fd384a2a5e/examples/go-sftp-server/main.go) to try to implement a SFTP server in my Go app.

I ran some tests and I can get a client to connect just fine but as soon as this client disconnects, the SFTP server reaches this code ([L140](https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/ec1c8caca60e03e3816cadfaad20a0fd384a2a5e/examples/go-sftp-server/main.go#L140)):

```golang
if err := server.Serve(); err == io.EOF {
    server.Close()
    log.Print("sftp client exited session.")
}
```

And after that, the server closes while I would like it to stay up and running, ready to accept more connections.

From what I've understood, when launched, the server blocks at this point ([L70](https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/ec1c8caca60e03e3816cadfaad20a0fd384a2a5e/examples/go-sftp-server/main.go#L70)) until it detects a client connection:

```golang
nConn, err := listener.Accept()
```

It looks like this whole example hasn't been designed to accept more than one connection and I haven't found any examples in the `ssh` or `sftp` packages to do what I want.

Comment: You need to call accept in a for loop and then handle each connection with a dedicated goroutine (so the main goroutine can go back to next Accept call)

Comment: @erik258 is correct here, use goroutines to handle each client connection in a separate goroutine, allowing the server to continue accepting new connections.

Comment: @erik258 Calling accept in a for loop was the missing bit to the example code to prevent the server to close after servicing one client connection.
Wrapping it in a goroutine allows the server to handle simultaneous connections.